# how to give the condition for ne-resize and nw-resize in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize

I want to resize the rectangle shape on mouseover event and so for that I want to stretch their four corner with their particular resize pointer. But for north-east stretch rectangle it shows the nw-resize pointer. But, I want for north-east stretch rectangle want to show the ne-resize pointer.

Here is my code,

```
anchor.on("mouseover", function() {
                     var layer = this.getLayer();
                     document.body.style.cursor = "ne-resize";
                     document.body.style.cursor = "nw-resize";
                     this.setStrokeWidth(4);
                     fill: "red";
                     strokeWidth: 2;
                     radius: 8;
                     layer.draw();
                 });
```

Thanks In Advance.